# I can't get ckeditor to allow anything but basic attributes and can't turn off/ configure the advanced content editor (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am running ckeditor 4.1.4 on a ruby on rails app. The advanced content editor seems to be stripping anything other than basic attributes.

For example, if I have a word doc with 'this is a test' where 'is a test' is bold, red and 28 point and looking at the contents of the clipboard with clipview shows

```
<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<!--StartFragment-->

<p class=MsoNormal>This <b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
style='font-size:28.0pt;line-height:107%;color:red'>is a test</span></b><o:p></o:p></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

<!--EndFragment-->
</body>

</html>
```

It would appear that it is picking up the color,size and bold attributes.

However, when I paste that into a text area using ckeditor and look at the source in ckeditor, I see

```
<p>This <strong>is a test</strong></p>
```

The attributes other than strong have been removed.

My body tag on the form is

```
  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.cktext_area :body,  :rows => 80, :cols => 120 %>
    </div>
```

I have gone into C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\ckeditor-4.1.4\app\assets\javascripts\ckeditor\config.js and added

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*);*{*}';
config.removeFormatAttributes = '';

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
```

I tried adding the three config lines inside the block and that didn't work. I read a suggestion about adding them outside the config block so I tried that. I did restart the server but it still strips out the additional attributes.

This is an intranet application and, given our situation, I'm not worried about content filtering. I just want the users to be able to copy and paste with all attributes.

------  edit 1

I looked at the source of the page and see

```
//<![CDATA[
(function() { if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') { if (CKEDITOR.instances['document_body'] == undefined) { CKEDITOR.replace('document_body', {"allowedContent":true}); } } else { setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50); } })();
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm not sure if the allowedContent statement should be working.

Comment: Pasting content from Office is extremely problematic for web editors and most strip extra tags by default nowadays. Look for configuration option of CKEditor to change it (but be warned it's not a good idea!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to [configure CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration), but the most simple one is passing object as a second parameter to `CKEDITOR.replace` (just as it's shown in your last piece of code).

However `allowedContent: true` can be not enough to enable pasting anything, because there are also paste filters in CKE, enabled in default in Chrome and Safari. If you're using that browser, CKE will strip off all classes, styles and `div` and `span` elements. To disable that behaviour, you should also pass `pasteFilter` option set to `null`:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    allowedContent: true,
    pasteFilter: null
} );
```

If you don't want to mess with configuring CKE, you can also disable paste filter on the fly:

```
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
    editor.pasteFilter.disable();
} );
```

However disabling that filter can lead to producing very messy HTML, so be warned!

More info about paste filter is available in [official documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter).

---edit:

Note that if you are pasting mainly from Word, there are also configuration options dedicated for that case: [`pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles) and [`pasteFromWordRemoveStyles`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFromWordRemoveStyles).

Comment: I suspect that my app is not reading the config.js file. For example, if I add ` config.font_names = 'Arial;Times New Roman;Verdana';` to `C:\Users\cmendla\RubymineProjects\research_library\app\assets\javascripts\ckeditor\config.js`  I still see 9 fonts. I would expect that if config.js was being read properly, then I would only see 2 fonts in the dropdown.

Comment: Is the format of config file correct? All config variables should be inside `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` function, as [shown in official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-using-the-config.js-file).

Comment: I finally got it working. The two that did it were the 'pastFromWordRemoveFontStyles` and 'pasteFromWordRemoveStyles` that you mentioned. I also found that if I made a change, I had to clobber assets, recompile assets (redoing if the error result was not 0) and then restarting the server

Comment: The official documentation says "Note that the paste filter is applied ONLY to external data.". However, I find that when I set pasteFilter: null in config, this solves problems I was having with *internal* copy and paste within the same CKEDITOR instance. Any thoughts on this apparent discrepancy between docs and reality?

Comment: In which browser do you test?